# reading xml making sure the order on nodes will be kept

Tags: javascript, dom-traversal

I am reading this XML with JavaScript
How can I make sure that I am reading the `<item>` element within `<record>` in the same order it exist on the xml (so [Robinson Crusoe] will come first then [Daniel Defo])

Will this work?

```
record[index].find("item:eq(0)").text();
record[index].find("item:eq(1)").text();
```

xml:

```
<result>
   <record>
        <item>Robinson Crusoe</item>
        <item>Daniel Defo</item>
   </record>
   <record>
        <item>Gullivers Travels</item>
        <item>Jonathan Swift</item>
   </record>
   <record>
        <item>Tom Jones</item>
        <item>Henry Fielding</item>
   </record>
</result>
```

Comment: Do you create the XML file or is it from an external data source? How are you loading and reading the XML document?

Comment: external legacy data source unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

With just a few lines of plain Javascript you convert the XML data into an array.  No reason to load a large framework like jQuery for this (unless it's used elsewhere). And as you can see from the example the array items are ordered the same as in the XML. This solution would work best with the simple XML structure of the question.

**Click show code and run snippet to see it work:**

```js
var i, xmlStr, items, list = [];

xmlStr = document.getElementById('data').value;

items = (new window.DOMParser())
  .parseFromString( xmlStr, 'text/xml')
  .getElementsByTagName('item');


for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  list.push(items[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
};


document.getElementById('stdout').value = JSON.stringify(list, null, ' ');
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 25em;
  height: 6em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>JS ARRAY</div>
<textarea id="stdout"></textarea>

<div>XML</div>
<textarea id="data">
  <result>
    <record>
      <item>Robinson Crusoe</item>
      <item>Daniel Defo</item>
    </record>
    <record>
      <item>Gullivers Travels</item>
      <item>Jonathan Swift</item>
    </record>
    <record>
      <item>Tom Jones</item>
      <item>Henry Fielding</item>
    </record>
  </result>
</textarea>
```

```
items = ( new window.DOMParser() )
  .parseFromString( xmlStr, 'text/xml' )
  .getElementsByTagName( 'item' );

for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) 
  list.push(items[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jquery this is the code which will process the xml input to give you sequential output.

`inputxml` contains your xml input for processing.

```
$(inputxml).find('record').each(function()
{
  var name = $(this).find('item').text(); 
});
```

or if you are interested in getting the first node only you can do like this

```
var result = $(inputxml).find('result record').first()
```

another way is

```
$(inputxml).find('result record:eq(0)')
```